# Measure cost of SELECT statement in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to measure how much does a select cost. Normally I would do it simply by getting the value of consistent gets before executing the statement and after, however, I'd like to wrap it in PL/SQL so that it's more generic. The problem I'm facing however, is how can I simply run a select without actually storing the result?

One of the ideas I had was to wrap it in a for loop like so

```
select value into getsBefore from v$sesstat ...

for dummy in (select name from my_table where city = 'XYZ') loop
  i := i;
end loop;

select value into getsAfter from v$sesstat ...
```

But this doesn't seem like a correct approach.

**I guess that I could simplify my question to - how can I `SELECT something INTO <nothing>`?**

Any ideas or hints on how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: The statement `null;` is more expressive of a NOP than `i := i;`

Comment: The cost of running a SELECT statement depends on a variety of factors that you have not specified, such as how many fetches are done, and how the results are processed. To measure this you need to actually run the statement in the manner in which it is expected that it will normally be run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try : `SELECT * bulk collect INTO [variable]`

See this as a reference [SELECT INTO Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm)

Comment: Thanks, the `SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO` is what I was looking for.

Comment: However, you shouldn't do this if your result set is large - this will blow up your PGA, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Answer (score 0):

Since the counters in `V$SESSSTAT` are absolute since a session is started there is no other way than to store a snapshot before an action and then subtract the snapshot from new one after the action is executed.

One of Tom Kyte's most used scripts is **RUNSTATS** meant to compare two actions performing the same thing to see which implementation is better.

You can find of the versions with description at http://betteratoracle.com/posts/12-runstats

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I do know that the snapshots there are absolute and therefore before returning the result, I subtract them (so from the provided examples, I would return `getsAfter - getsBefore`). The problem I have is how to execute the `SELECT` without the compiler complaining about not returning the result from the `SELECT` anywhere.

Comment: Do you really need to execute everything within single PL/SQL block? You can just store the value either to table or as global package variable and then execute the query (good option is using SQL\*Plus without printing the data) and then subtract the old gets from the new gets value. You can even create SQL\*Plus script where the query will be the parameter and it will do everything automatically.